# automatically add commas to a number in a label similar like Indian currency system

Tags: c#, html

```
using System.Globalization;

Label11.Text = totalPrice.ToString("0#,#0.00");
```

My problem is that I am showing this number in Indian currency format. Please help.

Comment: how about `string.Format("{0:C}",totalPrice)`

Comment: My String format is 99,99,99,99,999.99

Comment: can you paste your expected output string?

Comment: My expected output string is 99,99,99,99,999.99 But they show like this 999,999,999

Comment: then what's the problem if you use `"0#,#0.00"`  or `"{0:C}"`

Comment: output is not show my given string format.

Comment: then showing what?

Comment: have you tried Googling: `C# number to currency` ..?

Comment: Yes I am tried googling

Answer (score 0):

Paste the full code, the problem might not be where you think...

but try this

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
String convRupees = formatter.format(totalPrice);
Label1.Text = convRupees
```

EDIT - THIS IS HOW YOU DO IN JAVA, THIS IS IN C#

```
CultureInfo hindi = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
string conv = string.Format(hindi, "{0:c}", totalPrice.toString());
Label11.Text = conv;
```

Comment: is this java or C#?

Comment: That was java. Added c# way.

Comment: Hello Marcos Mateus, thanx for your answer but this is not working